# Why does transform not store the result in the other range?

Tags: c++, stl, c++17

I am a C++ newbie and am developing a C++17 application.

I want to iterate a vector of elements, and, for each element, produce a new version of that element and store the result into another vector. I want to do this in parallel. To do this, I can use `std::transform`. My code looks as follows:

```
std::vector<SimulatedBody> updated_bodies;
updated_bodies.reserve(bodies.size());
std::transform(std::execution::par_unseq, // make the loop parallel
               bodies.begin(),
               bodies.end(),
               updated_bodies.begin(), 
               [&](const SimulatedBody &body) {
                 auto new_body = body.updated(*quadtree, m_dt);
                 // new_body is correctly created, I can step here with a debugger
                 return new_body;
               });
```

`std:transform` requires the unary operation function object to be applied to have a signature equivalent to the following:

```
 Ret fun(const Type &a);
```

> The type Type must be such that an object of type InputIt can be
> dereferenced and then implicitly converted to Type. The type Ret must
> be such that an object of type OutputIt can be dereferenced and
> assigned a value of type Ret.​

Moreover, since that I am using the parallel execution policy, it requires the iterator of the output vector to be a forward iterator (therefore, I can't use `back_inserter`).

I think that my code meets these requirements. In particular, in my case, `Ret` is a `SimulatedBody`; `OutputIt` is a `SimulatedBody` too; and `SimulatedBody` has both a copy assignment operator and a move assignment operator. (I point out that `SimulatedBody` inerits from `Body`).

```
#ifdef DEBUG_MOVE_ASSIGNMENT_OPERATOR
SimulatedBody &SimulatedBody::operator=(SimulatedBody &&other) noexcept {
  Body::operator=(std::move(other));
  std::cout << "SimulatedBody move assignment operator\n";
  m_velocity = std::move(other.m_velocity);  // NOLINT(bugprone-use-after-move)
  return *this;
}
#else
SimulatedBody &SimulatedBody::operator=(SimulatedBody &&other) noexcept =
    default;
#endif

#ifdef DEBUG_MOVE_ASSIGNMENT_OPERATOR
Body &Body::operator=(Body &&other) noexcept {
  std::cout << "Body move assignment operator\n";
  m_position = std::move(m_position);
  m_mass = other.m_mass;
  return *this;
}
#else
Body &Body::operator=(Body &&other) noexcept = default;
#endif
```

When the `transform` code executes, it prints that the `new_body`ies are moved into the `updated_bodies` vector's range:

```
Body move assignment operator
SimulatedBody move assignment operator
Body move assignment operator
SimulatedBody move assignment operator
Body move assignment operator
SimulatedBody move assignment operator
...
```

However, to my surprise, at the end of the `transform`, `updated_bodies` is empty: I expected `updated_bodies` to contain the same number of elements of `bodies`.
Why is this the case?

- Is it because I called `updated_bodies.reserve()`? I think this makes sense; I need to preallocate some memory in the output vector to host the transformed elements.
- Does the move assignment operator have issues I can't see?

Comment: Try using a https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter

Comment: This would work, but the transform has to have a parallel execution policy, which impedes the use of a back_inserter. I clarified the question.

Comment: In that case, i would suggest that the suggested duplicate is correct. Use `resize()` instead of `reserve()`

Comment: But `resize()` requires the `SimulatedBody` to be default constructible. It is not: it mandatorily needs to be constructed using its two-parameters constructor.

Comment: You could also pass the desired size when constructing the vector and omit the `resize()` call.

Comment: Can you construct an object with some "dummy" values and then let the vector copy-construct the new vector elements (using the appropriate constructor overload)?

Comment: @Blastfurnace Yes, I can, but it makes the code a bit ugly because `SimulatedBody` should not be default constructible. That's why I thought that using `reserve()` was a good idea: it just preallocates some memory.

Apparently, I discovered that `transform` requires the output vector to have the same `size()` of the source vector; however, `reserve` does not change the size.
It seems that I am out of luck and must define a default constructor. :(

Comment: I agree, hopefully the parallel transform makes up for the cost of constructing objects that will just be overwritten.

Comment: Fortunately, I perceive no significant difference, as the computationally expensive part is the `body.updated()` call, and not the object construction. However, do you happen to know if there is an alternative which does not require the output vector to be resized?

Comment: I can imagine a solution where each thread pushes elements into its own dedicated vector and then collecting the results when all threads are done.  That is obviously more complicated than a single call to a parallel algorithm and not guaranteed to be faster.

Comment: You could do it as a `std::transform_reduce` but that's basically the same thing @Blastfurnace is suggesting. I would probably look at trying to accomplish the task without `std::transform` it doesn't seem to be appropriate for your needs. FWIW, there is a proposal to add a new function to vector to do exactly what you want. Reserve the room, fill it with data, then say your size is now X. Its just a proposal though you might be able to find an implementation of it somewhere that you can crib off of if its that important to you.